# user and status details without any form authentication

Tags: rest, twitter

I have a class where developer input only a twitter user profile url (`http://twitter.com/shiplu`) or a status url (`https://twitter.com/shiplu/status/273878249271066624`). Then the class will have to parse the `status_id` or `screen_name` from it. Its done by regex on url.

Now the tool should return some meta data about it. For example if the url is twitter profile it'll also return latest 5 (public) statuses, followers, short bio etc. It can be easily done by twitter REST api. But it requires authentication. And I dont want to use authentication. It can be easily parsed from the html twitter provides. But HTML changes over time.

An ideal solution would be any Rest API that does not use any authentication. I dont mind if the profile is non-public or protected. The tool should not read such profile. Only publicly available resources will be read.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the (REST) API you will use, there will be one moment where you will have to ask Twitter the information that you want. At this moment, you will need to authenticate. So you cannot escape to authentication if you want to use a Twitter API. So if you do not want to authenticate, your only solution will be parsing HTML.

Comment: So is there any way to authenticate without asking a user to authenticate an app?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im : Nope. It is not in the OAuth (Twitter's authentication system) principles. With the OAuth authentication process, the user gives an authorization to the third party app (or software, program...) to use its account. It is normal that the user decides to which apps he will authorize to use its Twitter account. So you have to ask the user to authorize the app.